# Sending emails with outlook reminder

Tags: c#, email, outlook

## Introduction

I currently have a C# method that allows me to send emails (see below).  The emails are being sent via a Microsoft Exchange server, and the emails are read using an Outlook client. I would like to add additional functionality to this method so that I can include a follow-up reminder for 24 hours after the send time. From what I have read online, I need to use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it.

## Current method

```
using System.Net.Mail;

public void SendEmail(string host, string un, string pw, string from, string to, string subject, string body)
{
     MailMessage email = new MailMessage(from, to);
     email.Subject = subject;
     email.Body = body;

     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
     client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     client.EnableSsl = true;
     client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(un, pw);
     client.Host = host;
     client.Send(email);
}
```

## What I Have Tried

I believe I need to use the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem` class to create the email instead of the `MailMessage` class I have been using. However I am unsure about 2 things:

- How to connect to the server and send the email. I tried using the `SmtpClient` class as I was before, but I can't pass it a `MailItem`.
- I'm not sure if my code to create the reminder is correct. I haven't been able to send the message, so I also haven't been able to see if the reminder is displayed in Outlook correctly. If anyone has experience using reminders, comments on how I am creating the reminder would also be appreciated.

Here is the code I have used to create the email and reminder:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    
public void SendEmail(string host, string un, string pw, string from, string to, string subject, string body)
{
    MailItem email = new MailItem();
    email.ReminderTime = new DateTime();
    email.ReminderTime = DateTime.Now;
    email.ReminderTime.AddDays(1);
    email.ReminderSet = true;
    email.Subject = subject;
    email.Body = body;
}
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2050ff97-e097-4e04-b06f-ef50d1741740/sending-emails-with-follow-up-header-and-reply-date?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: You mean you want to send a second reminder email, or you want to add something to the user's Calendar? It's not totally clear. But either way, Interop is not a good solution.

Comment: I do not want to send a second email. I want to modify the email before sending it to the recipient so in the recipient's email client a reminder shows them it is due 24 hours after the email was sent.

Comment: emails don't carry reminders, that isn't part of the email specification. Anything like what you're describing would have to take advantage of some specific feature in Outlook/Exchange. Are you talking about setting a to-do flag on it in outlook? Or adding a calendar entry with a reminder?

Comment: I would be interested in trying both options.

Comment: Ok. Well does your exchange server have exchange web services enabled?

Comment: I think it does. I'll have to check with our email admin though. I know we use the same credentials for logging into our computer and our email, and we can update our password via office.com

Comment: Sounds like maybe you have Office365 and Exchange online then? If so you can use the Graph API (rather than the older exchange web services) to create calendar events, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into the Graph API.

Comment: e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp